# Can I tell if a std::string represents a number using stringstream?

Tags: c++, numbers, stringstream, words

Apparently this is suposed to work in showing if a string is numerical, for example "12.5" == yes, "abc" == no. However I get a no reguardless of the input.

```
std::stringstream ss("2");
double d; ss >> d;
if(ss.good()) {std::cout<<"number"<<std::endl;}
else {std::cout<<"other"<<std::endl;}
```

Comment: Does "12.5 abc" qualify as "a string is numerical"? If "no", none of the answers so far apply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use an `istringstream` so that it knows it's trying to parse input. Also, just check the result of the extraction directly rather than using `good` later.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream ss("2");
    double d = 0.0;
    if(ss >> d) {std::cout<<"number"<<std::endl;}
    else {std::cout<<"other"<<std::endl;}
}
```

Comment: How does "it knows it's trying to parse input" matter at all?  Perhaps good for code clarity, but I see no technical reason.

Comment: You're not checking for extra content.  "2 abc" isn't a number, for example - it's a string with embedded whitespace.  IIRC, the solution is to check {{ss.peek() == EOF}} (everything was consumed) or maybe by looking at {{ss.gcount()}}.

Answer (score 8):

Don't use good()!  Test if the stream is [failed or not](http://codepad.org/ygisKfA9):

```
if (ss)
```

Good tells you if any of eofbit, badbit, or failbit are set, while fail() tells you about badbit and failbit.  You almost never care about eofbit unless you *already* know the stream is failed, so you almost never want to use good.

Note that testing the stream directly, as above, is exactly equivalent to:

```
if (!ss.fail())
```

Conversely, !ss is equivalent to ss.fail().

---

Combining the extraction into the conditional expression:

```
if (ss >> d) {/*...*/}
```

Is exactly equivalent to:

```
ss >> d;
if (ss) {/*...*/}
```

---

However, you probably want to test if the complete string can be converted to a double, which is a bit more involved.  Use boost::lexical_cast which already handles all of the cases.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to check whether a `string` contains *only* a number and nothing else (except whitespace), use this:

```
#include <sstream>

bool is_numeric (const std::string& str) {
    std::istringstream ss(str);
    double dbl;
    ss >> dbl;      // try to read the number
    ss >> std::ws;  // eat whitespace after number

    if (!ss.fail() && ss.eof()) {
        return true;  // is-a-number
    } else {
        return false; // not-a-number
    }
}
```

The `ss >> std::ws` is important for accepting numbers with trailing whitespace such as `"24 "`.

The `ss.eof()` check is important for rejecting strings like `"24 abc"`. It ensures that we reached the end of the string after reading the number (and whitespace).

Test harness:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::string tests[8] = {
            "", "XYZ", "a26", "3.3a", "42 a", "764", " 132.0", "930 "
    };
    std::string is_a[2] = { "not a number", "is a number" };
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(tests)/sizeof(std::string); ++i) {
        std::cout << std::setw(8) << "'" + tests[i] + "'" << ": ";
        std::cout << is_a [is_numeric (tests[i])] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
      '': not a number
   'XYZ': not a number
   'a26': not a number
  '3.3a': not a number
  '42 a': not a number
   '764': is a number
' 132.0': is a number
  '930 ': is a number
```

Comment: I like the solution, but using my compiler on OSX, the `ss << std::ws` sets the fail flag if there is no whitespace to be read. I have to check for eof prior to flushing whitespace.

Answer (score -1):

```
int str2int (const string &str) {
  stringstream ss(str);
  int num;
  if((ss >> num).fail())
  { 
      //ERROR: not a number
  }
  return num;
}
```